# Blade templates - Toggle auto escape on the fly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a template which calls a number of built in macros which I am including this template from several other places.

Sometimes, I need all of the macros to be called like this:

{{ Form::label('foo', 'Foo') }}

Other times I need them all to be called like this:

{{{ Form::label('foo', 'Foo') }}}

At the moment, I have two separate templates which are identical except for the extra { }, which means I have to edit two files every time I want to change anything.

Is there a way to switch the auto escaping on/off, so that I can use the same file for both situations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no feature in Laravel that would allow you to do that -- additionally, it'd probably be a bad idea from a code maintenance/security-audit point of view. Looking at a template a few weeks later and not knowing which variables were or were not escaped would be madness.

If you need to do this, "The Right" way would be to [extend Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#extending-blade) with your own directive -- something like `@escapeIsConfigIsOn` and then put your logic for when to escape content in there.  The top level function `e` is what blade uses internally for escaping.

```
#File: login/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php
function e($value)
{
    return htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
}
```